# Cannot target exact part of string using Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, bash

my sample input looks like this.

```
1727699761 24929 0.0  0.0 103164 2688 ?        S    12:23   0:00 sshd: driscollj1@notty
1727699761 24930 0.0  0.0 28896  2344 ?        Ss   12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
1727699761 24940 0.0  0.0 103188 2644 ?        S    12:24   0:00 sshd: driscollj1@pts/9
1727699761 24941 0.0  0.2 37800  8996 pts/9    Ss   12:24   0:00 -bash
1727699761 25140 0.0  0.0 31200  2268 pts/9    R+   12:38   0:00 ps -U driscollj1 -u driscoll
```

All that I need is the the Command portion, in this case,

```
sshd: driscollj1@notty
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
sshd: driscollj1@pts/9
-bash
ps -U driscollj1 -u driscoll
```

I am working in Ruby and the regex that I am currently using looks like this.

```
userProcess = `ps h -U driscollj1 -u driscollj1 u`.scan(/:\d\d (.*)/)
```

But I am capturing the time before the section that I actually want as well and I am not sure how to target what I do want without getting the time in front of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to change your `ps` command to only return the command portion (`-o command` maybe?).  But if you can't do that, this scan should work.  It will match the "0:00" but not "12:23" as it requires only a single digit before the colon (and a space).

```
.scan(/\s\d:\d\d (.*)/)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that:

```
sampletext.split(/\n/).each do |line|
    puts line.split(/\s+/, 11).last
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the contents through `cut` to get only the field you want:

```
ps $args | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f11
```

The actual command is in the 11th field.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but OP wanted ruby not Unix, which is why I found a ruby equivalent.

Also, you'd need a `cut -d ' ' -f11-` because the commands contain spaces too

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about Ruby, but I do a lot of text processing with Unix, and the way I would approach this problem is using a delimiter to split the string into multiple elements, and then abandon the first 9 elements, then concatenate the remaining.

From a quick online lookup, this seems to be a way to implement the solution in Ruby:

```
str = `command`
# something to iterate line by line in str...
cur_line.split(" ").drop(9).join(' ')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you would want to `.join(' ')` rather than `.join`

Comment: Oh yeah, we lost the delimiters when we split. Oops, my bad. Thank you!

Comment: @UriAgassi: Edited answer. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have that exact string formatted into a table, then counting the characters will do better than using a regex. It would be robust and flexible. Given your string:

```
s = <<_
1727699761 24929 0.0  0.0 103164 2688 ?        S    12:23   0:00 sshd: driscollj1@notty
1727699761 24930 0.0  0.0 28896  2344 ?        Ss   12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
1727699761 24940 0.0  0.0 103188 2644 ?        S    12:24   0:00 sshd: driscollj1@pts/9
1727699761 24941 0.0  0.2 37800  8996 pts/9    Ss   12:24   0:00 -bash
1727699761 25140 0.0  0.0 31200  2268 pts/9    R+   12:38   0:00 ps -U driscollj1 -u driscoll
_
```

This simple command:

```
s.each_line.map{|l| l[65...-1]}
```

will give:

```
[
  "sshd: driscollj1@notty",
  "/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server",
  "sshd: driscollj1@pts/9",
  "-bash",
  "ps -U driscollj1 -u driscoll"
]
```